# Ordenar Relaciones (ManyToMany) sin duplicar registros

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Durante días he estado tratando de ordenar una serie de consultas pasando como parámetro objects.order_by("relation").distinct() de tipo "ManyToMany" pero siempre me duplica las consulta "x" el numero de relaciones, siendo la ultima la deseada.

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  groups = models.ManyToManyField('Group', through='GroupMember', related_name='people')

  class Meta:
      ordering = ['name']

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

  class Meta:
      ordering = ['name']

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name

class GroupMember(models.Model):
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='membership')
  group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='membership')
  type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return "%s is in group %s (as %s)" % (self.person, self.group, self.type)

# Deseo ordear (Person) por el orden deseado en dos campos.
Person.objects.all().order_by("membership__type", "group__name").distinct("id")
```

Note que a pesar de agregar "distinct()" me está duplicando los valores de la consulta, mi pregunta es cual es el motivo y como solucionarlo. La base de datos que estoy usando PostgreSQL. Gracias.

Comment: una opcion mas sencilla seria usar RAW SQL https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/

Comment: ¿Puedes especificar que es lo que quieres obtener? no se entiende muy bien.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de utilizar `order_by` utiliza la función `values_list` y luego aplicale el `distinct`.

### Ejemplo

```
Person.objects.all().values_list("membership__type", "group__name","id").distinct("id")
```

La función values_list sacará un conjunto de array por cada `Person` y aplicandole el distinct filtrará los que tenga el id repetido y te devolverá los únicos.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.